# My Samsonite lock is jammed

Tags: uk, luggage

My samsonite 325 F'lite lock won't flip over to opposite lid lip on the case. I have tried lubricating with wd40 to no avail. Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't appear to be about travel.

Comment: You may need to visit a luggage repair shop or Samsonite dealer (or ship to one) to arrange a repair if the bag is broken.

Comment: Disagree that this is off topic. Having a suitcase jammed open is certainly something relevant to travelers. This is a useful question and a nice change from visa questions, which is 90% of what gets asked here!